# Possible bug with `list2env()`

Tags: r, environment, evaluation

In my R package, I have a function that looks essentially like this:

```
li <- list(foo = "bar", bar = "foo")
f1 <- function(list) {
  list2env(li, parent = parent.frame())
}

f1(li)
```

This function had unexpected behavior, so on a whim I tried this modification:

```
f1 <- function(list) {
  list2env(li)
}
```

This should have exactly the same behavior, since `parent.frame()` is the default argument to `parent` in `list2env()`. However, this code worked. This code elucidates the problem:

```
li <- list(foo = "bar", bar = "foo")
f1 <- function(list) {
  env <- list2env(li)
  rlang::env_parents(env, last = emptyenv())
}

f2 <- function(list) {
  env2 <- list2env(li, parent = parent.frame())
  rlang::env_parents(env2, last = emptyenv())
}

f1(li)

#[[1]]   <env: 0x5afd59d8d730> 
#[[2]] $ <env: global>
#[[3]] $ <env: tools:rstudio>
#[[4]] $ <env: package:stats>
#[[5]] $ <env: package:graphics>
#[[6]] $ <env: package:grDevices>
#[[7]] $ <env: package:utils>
#[[8]] $ <env: package:datasets>
#[[9]] $ <env: package:methods>
#[[10]] $ <env: Autoloads>
#[[11]] $ <env: package:base>
#[[12]] $ <env: empty>

f2(li)

#[[1]]   <env: global>
#[[2]] $ <env: tools:rstudio>
#[[3]] $ <env: package:stats>
#[[4]] $ <env: package:graphics>
#[[5]] $ <env: package:grDevices>
#[[6]] $ <env: package:utils>
#[[7]] $ <env: package:datasets>
#[[8]] $ <env: package:methods>
#[[9]] $ <env: Autoloads>
#[[10]] $ <env: package:base>
#[[11]] $ <env: empty>
```

It looks like `parent.frame()` is evaluated earlier when it is passed as a function argument explicitly than when it is just the default argument. This seems like a bug to me. Also, the default argument behavior seems more correct to me, because it provides the most general semantics: if you want the environment where `list2env()` is called, use `parent.frame(n = 1)`, and then increase `n` to move up the search path. Otherwise, it is hard to access the calling environment (unless you leave the argument blank).

Assuming that this is the behavior that R wants, this is an easy fix:

```
list2env_fixed <- function (x, envir = NULL, parent = parent.frame(),
                            hash = (length(x) > 100), size = max(29L, length(x))) {
  if (is.null(envir))
    envir <- new.env(hash = hash, parent = eval(substitute(parent)), size = size)
  .Internal(list2env(x, envir))
}

f2_fixed <- function(list) {
  env2 <- list2env_fixed(li, parent = parent.frame())
  rlang::env_parents(env2, last = emptyenv())
}

f2_fixed(li)

#[[1]]   <env: 0x5afd59d8d730>
#[[2]] $ <env: global>
#[[3]] $ <env: tools:rstudio>
#[[4]] $ <env: package:stats>
#[[5]] $ <env: package:graphics>
#[[6]] $ <env: package:grDevices>
#[[7]] $ <env: package:utils>
#[[8]] $ <env: package:datasets>
#[[9]] $ <env: package:methods>
#[[10]] $ <env: Autoloads>
#[[11]] $ <env: package:base>
#[[12]] $ <env: empty>
```

Does this analysis seem correct? Should I submit a bug report? I assume I don't need to submit a patch, since the issue is only with R-level code.

Answer (score 1):

The two situations are *not* the same.

`parent.frame()` refers to the caller of the frame where it is appears.  In one case `parent.frame()` appears in the function -- default arguments are part of the function definition -- and in the other case it is passed to the function and appears in the caller.  Thus in the first case it refers to the parent frame of the function, which is the caller, and in the second case it refers to the caller of the caller.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense -- it seems like there should be a way to refer to the current environment with an explicit argument, though. Is there a reason not to delay evaluation to provide that?

Comment: `environment()` returns the current environment.